# Can I set up wifi using netgear

Tags: wireless, internet

I have a N300 Wireless USB adapter, can i set this up on my computer? Do i need to hook it up to a wired connection and install something?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have wifi, you just set the adapter up on your computer, then connect to your wifi as you would with any computer.

If you can't get it set up on your computer, try looking at the installation and setup section near the bottom of:

http://www.netgear.com/service-providers/products/home/networking/wifi-adapters/WNA3100.aspx#tab-support

Comment: Alright I have windows on another drive, it has netgear and downloaded so is there anyway to bring it over? Also that download wont work. I have the CD it came with but I can put it on here. So how do I get it to read My USB wireless Adapter. Is there a program I need to get. I also believe I'm on 2.02 Beta2 (at least that's what it says when I start up my PC) Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, sorry. I have used a similar (maybe even the same one) wifi adapter, and as far as I can remember, it just worked automatically.